# How to join two very large dataframes together with same columns?

Tags: python, r, pandas, dataframe

I have two datasets that look like this:

`df1`:

| Date | City | State | Quantity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2019-01 | Chicago | IL | 35 |
| 2019-01 | Orlando | FL | 322 |
| ... | .... | ... | ... |
| 2021-07 | Chicago | IL | 334 |
| 2021-07 | Orlando | FL | 4332 |

`df2`:

| Date | City | State | Sales |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2019-01 | Chicago | IL | 30 |
| 2019-01 | Orlando | FL | 319 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 2021-07 | Chicago | IL | 331 |
| 2021-07 | Orlando | FL | 4000 |

They are **EXTREMELY** large datasets, to the point where `pd.merge()` and `dd.merge()` do not work, and my kernel gives me memory errors. However, I found that concatenating the two of those does not give me the memory error. My desired dataset, `out2` looks like this:

| Date | City | State | Quantity | Sales |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2019-01 | Chicago | IL | 35 | 30 |
| 2019-01 | Orlando | FL | 322 | 319 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 2021-07 | Chicago | IL | 334 | 331 |
| 2021-07 | Orlando | FL | 4332 | 4000 |

I used the following code:

```
out2=dd.concat([df1,df2],join='outer')
```

but my new dataset looks like this:

| Date | City | State | Quantity | Sales |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2019-01 | Chicago | IL | 35 | NaN |
| 2019-01 | Orlando | FL | 322 | NaN |
| 2019-01 | Chicago | IL | NaN | 30 |
| 2019-01 | Orlando | FL | NaN | 319 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 2021-07 | Chicago | IL | 334 | NaN |
| 2021-07 | Orlando | FL | 4332 | NaN |
| 2021-07 | Chicago | IL | NaN | 331 |
| 2021-07 | Orlando | FL | NaN | 4000 |

How can I get my desired dataset without running into memory error issues, without using the `pd.merge` function?

Comment: Since you've added the R tag, have you tried `data.table`? I'm not sure how big you mean by big, but if you look at [the H2O joining benchmarks](https://h2oai.github.io/db-benchmark/) R's `data.table` performs very well on data sets ~5GB, it does a full order of magnitude better than pandas. However on data sets about 50GB Spark or `pydatatable` are the best bets.

Comment: One thing that may help you work around memory limitations is to convert all character-type columns to factors. It will hugely decrease memory footprint and maybe they'll fit your memory (I don't know how large they are).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If performance is not critical, you could create a defaultdict of dict and use the first three values as the dict key and then add quantity and sales to the value dict. This would allow you to process the files without reading them into memory first.

```
from collections import defaultdict
from pathlib import Path

paths = [(Path.home() / 'file1.csv', 'Quantity'), (Path.home() / 'file2.csv', 'Sales')]
results = defaultdict(dict)

for path, value_column in paths:
    with path.open('r') as f:
        for line in f:
            parts = [s.strip() for s in line.split(',')]
            key = tuple(parts[0:-1])
            results[key][value_column] = parts[-1]

combined = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(data=list(results.keys()), columns=['Date', 'City', 'State']), 
                      pd.DataFrame(list(results.values()))], axis=1)
```